# Can't make maths equation - possibly Calligraphy?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have included a picture of a maths equation that I need to convert to LaTeX. However I just can't figure out how to convert the first two symbols or figure out what they are/stand for.

The picture is blurry but it looks like calligraphy

```
  \mathitcal
```

but I know it's not.

[image: Picture Here]

Comment: Looks like Caligraphic N and P

Comment: Perhaps `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` and `$\mathscr{N}\!\mathscr{P} \cap \mbox{co} - \mathscr{N}\!\mathscr{P}$` (see [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Tcz.png)).

Comment: But doesn't a P in calligraphy go straight without curves? or am I wrong? @A.Ellett

Comment: Regardless, this is covered in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764) (possible duplicate).